# Notice: Undefined index: (It does not identify radio buttons I have in my form!)

Tags: php, html, webforms

To keep it short:

I have a radio button but wehne I submit my form it gives me the folllwoing notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: education_check in C:\xampp\htdocs\FDPW... on
>   line 87

**More details:**

I have a form in which I have the following radio button:

```
              <div class="span11">
                    <h3>A.Education and Professional Qualifications Check:</h3>
                        <div class="span6">                                              
                       Education Checked?
                        </div>
                        <label class="radio">
                            <input id="education_check" name="education_check" value="1"  type="radio" <?php if(isset($_POST["education_check"])){ if($_POST["education_chec"]== "1"){ echo "checked"; }} ?> class="span1"> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">
                            <input id="education_check" name="education_check" value="0"  type="radio" <?php if(isset($_POST["education_check"])){ if($_POST["education_check"]== "0"){ echo "checked"; }} ?>  class="span1"> No

                        </label>
                </div>
```

When I submit I code I have the following call:

```
if(isset($_POST["submits"])) {
        $Message = helperFunctions::UpdateTableHrForms($id, $_POST["dob_city"], $_POST["dob_province"], $_POST["dob_country"],$_POST["education_check"]);
        $_POST["submits"] = null;
        echo $Message;
}
```

And here is my function in my helper:

```
public static function UpdateTableHrForms(
    $id,$dob_city,$dob_province,$dob_country,$education_check) 
     {
    $conn = new mysqlcon();
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "INSERT into `hr_forms` (`id`,`dob_city`,`dob_province`,`dob_country`,`education_check`)VLUES (:id,:dob_city,:dob_province,:dob_country,:education_check)";               
    try {
            if (helperFunctions::CheckIDExistHrForms($id) == 0) {
                $result = $conn->prepare($query);                                               
                $result->execute(array('id'=>$id,'dob_city'=>$dob_city,'dob_province'=>$dob_province,'dob_country'=>$dob_country,'education_check'=>$education_check));
                $Msg = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-success\">
                            <strong>Tips! </strong>
                                Data is successfully saved to database.
                            <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
                        </div>";
            } else {
                $Msg = "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-error\">
                            <strong>Error! </strong>
                                This employee's information is already existed in the system.
                            <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
                        </div>";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
            $Msg = $e; /* "<div style=\"text-align:center;\" class=\"alert alert-error\">
              <strong>Error! </strong>
              This associate information cannot save in the system.
              <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button>
              </div>"; */
        }
    return $Msg;
}
```

But keeps giving me the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: education_check in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDPW... on line 87

Comment: Is line 87 the one referencing $_POST['education_check'] in the call to UpdateTableHrForms()?

Comment: add a print_r($_POST); in there to see exactly what is coming through in the form submission. Is it possible this particular form field is outside the <form></form> tags?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Comment: @cske Did you read the question at all?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you cannot have two elements with the id `"education_check"`.

Comment: @Chris Rasco: If the user doesn't check a checkbox there's no posted data for that checkbox. So: $_POST["education_check"] - doesn't exists. Therefore , you get the "undefined index" notice.

Comment: @cske Wouldn't it have been easier to say that than posting a link to w3.org?

Comment: echo 'checked="checked"'; http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user dohesn't check a checkbox there's no posted data for that checkbox.
So:

`$_POST["education_check"]` - doesn't exists.

Therefore , you get the "undefined index" notice.

The problem is in this line:

```
$Message = helperFunctions::UpdateTableHrForms($id, $_POST["dob_city"], 
$_POST["dob_province"], $_POST["dob_country"],$_POST["education_check"]);
```

While on the form you're acting correctly when asking 'isset' before trying to access the posted data.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["education_check"])){ if($_POST["education_chec"]== "1"){ echo
```

(BTW , you forgot a "k" in the second condition on that line).

**The solution is:**

```
$education_check = (isset($_POST['education_check'])) ? 1 : 0;

$Message = helperFunctions::UpdateTableHrForms($id, $_POST["dob_city"], 
$_POST["dob_province"], $_POST["dob_country"],$education_check);
```

Comment: And if I'm right I have to add

$education_check = (isset($_POST['education_check'])) ? $_POST['education_check'] : 0; 

Right? Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: Kind of, basically the value of checked radiobox is 1 , but you can do it that way either.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined Index means that when you are referencing the variable education_check it is non existent ... make sure there is actually data being placed into that variable.

Comment: It seems that I placed into the varibale but nootice says not; I put the related code here; do you think I'm missing something?Thnaks